# ember simple auth with rails devise username instead of email?

Tags: authentication, ember.js, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, ember-simple-auth

I have a rails api that I am using devise for the login routine. I hooked ember into that via ember simple auth. Got it up and running using a typical devise email and password. I typically configure devise though to use LDAP authentication which works great. The issue I am having is that I use a username for my LDAP login, not an email address. I usually change devise to look for a username and not an email address which I have done.

I am now getting a 401 unauthorized and looking at the params it looks like I am still sending an email across.

Can you change ember simple auth to send a username and not email? If so how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the devise authorizer and set the `identificationAttributeName` to `username`

```
// app/authorizers/devise.js
import DeviseAuthorizer from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/devise';

export default DeviseAuthorizer.extend({
  identificationAttributeName: 'username'
});
```

Source: [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/cd6d9e89e2f5979712d5229f54a9bbc886e288a1/README.md#customizing-an-authorizer)

Comment: One more question for this. How do I display the username on the page as being logged in. I have been trying currentUser.user, currentUser.username etc. and haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Try session.data.authenticated.user_id. but it is better to create a service for currentUser as described here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/cd6d9e89e2f5979712d5229f54a9bbc886e288a1/guides/managing-current-user.md

Comment: Thanks I think I see the problem. I do not seem to be authenticated on the ember side. If I check for session.isAuthenticated on the page it is coming back false. When I look in ember inspector under session/main it says isAuthenticated true. I have to figure out what is going on.